# Java Prime finder efficiency

Tags: java, performance, square-root

I want to sum all the primes that have a value less than 10.

This is my code:

```
    boolean kontroll = true;
    long limit = 10;
    long checker = 2;
    long sum = 0;

    while (checker < 10) {
        for (long i = 3; i < Math.sqrt(checker); i += 2) {
            if (checker % 2 == 0) {
                kontroll = false;
                break;
            } else {
                if (checker % i == 0) {
                    kontroll = false;
                } 
            }
        } if (kontroll) {
            sum += checker; 
            System.out.println("Prim: " + checker);
        }
        checker++;
        kontroll = true;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

I get this output:

```
Prim: 2
Prim: 3
Prim: 4
Prim: 5
Prim: 6
Prim: 7
Prim: 8
Prim: 9
44
```

What is wrong with this build? If I remove `Math.sqrt(checker);` the program works, but is slow. Can't I take the square root of the checker?

Comment: Assign a **float q = Math.sqrt(checker);** before the while statement, then have  **for(long i=2 ; i <q ; I+=2 )** instead.  This should speed your code.

Comment: @ArifBurhan Why do you use `float`?

Comment: @Aminorph: Your program doesn't correctly identify the prime numbers and hence the sum is also incorrect. I think its partly because you set "kontroll = true" at the end of the while loop and in the next iteration, if the for loop isn't executed even once, then the next number will always be used to calculate the sum

Comment: @MikeCAT double works just as well, but you don't need high accuracy here since you are comparing against a **long**.

Comment: @ArifBurhan Using `float` gave me [compile error](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Rg7RfuzvuKawnPuj). You are compareing against a `long`, so why not `long`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`3` is larger than `Math.sqrt(checker)` when `checker` is non-negative number and is 8 or less.

Try this:

```
boolean kontroll = true;
long limit = 10;
long checker = 2;
long sum = 0;

while (checker < 10) {
    if (checker != 2 && checker % 2 == 0) { // move this check out of the loop and correct condition
        kontroll = false;
    } else {
        long max = (long)Math.sqrt(checker);
        for (long i = 3; i <= max; i += 2) { // change < to <=
            if (checker % i == 0) {
                kontroll = false;
                break; // add break for better performance
            } 
        }
    }
    if (kontroll) {
        sum += checker; 
        System.out.println("Prim: " + checker);
    }
    checker++;
    kontroll = true;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: You could improve `if (checker...` to read `if (checker % 2 == 0) { kontroll = checker == 2; } else { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Your `kontroll` variable is assigned with `true`, and you're looping from `3` to `sqrt(checker)` that in your case `checker` will below `10`.

So, your code will enter your loop only once, when the `checker = 10` (`3 < sqrt(10)`) and the other times, they just go past through to

```
if (kontroll) { //remember, your kontroll assigned to true =)
    sum += checker; 
    System.out.println("Prim: " + checker);
}
```

and the sum will always be added. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

An optimized version that prints prime numbers up to some number.

```
final List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(2));

/**
 * Print prime numbers up to {@code n} inclusive
 */
public void findPrimes(int n) {
    // check only odd numbers
    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i += 2) {
        isPrime(i);
    }
    System.out.println(primes);
}

// a function which does have side effects (adds to the primes collection)
private boolean isPrime(final int i) {
    // we really need to check for divisors only up to sqrt
    int sqrt = (int)Math.sqrt(i);
    // and we really need to find only prime divisors since any
    // number can be written as a product of prime numbers
    for (int prime : primes) {
        if (i % prime == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if (prime > sqrt) {
            break;
        }
    }
    primes.add(i);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for this!